# About Arrow Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Confused about how arrow functions work...In this particular example:

```
class VillageState {
  constructor(place, parcels) {
    this.place = place;
    this.parcels = parcels;
  }

  move(destination) {
    if (!roadGraph[this.place].includes(destination)) {
      return this;
    } else {
      let parcels = this.parcels.map(p => {
        if (p.place != this.place) return p;
        return {place: destination, address: p.address};
      }).filter(p => p.place != p.address);
      return new VillageState(destination, parcels);
    }
  }
}
```

Particulary in,

```
let parcels = this.parcels.map(p => {
        if (p.place != this.place) return p;
        return {place: destination, address: p.address};})
```

What I can tell is that p is the argument of this arrow function but it is going to be replaced for what variable in this example? The only argument in the move method is destination but that's not going to replace p...I can't understand it.

Comment: `map()` passes in each element in the array, as the first argument.  So `p` will iterably be each element in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I can tell is that p is the argument of this arrow function but it is going to be replaced for what variable in this example?

It won't be replaced by any variable. The `map` function calls its callback once for each entry in the array. Each time it calls the callback (the arrow function), it passes in the entry's value. That's what the arrow function receives in its `p` parameter.

So for instance, suppose `this.parcels` looked like this:

```
this.parcels = [
    {
        place: "a",
        description: "parcel a"
    },
    {
        place: "b",
        description: "parcel b"
    },
    {
        place: "c",
        description: "parcel c"
    }
];
```

With those `parcels`, `map` would call the arrow function three times. `p` in the first call would refer to the `{ place: "a", description: "parcel a" }` object. `p` in the second call would refer to the `{ place: "b", description: "parcel b" }` object, and `p` in the third call would refer to the `{ place: "c", description: "parcel c" }` object.

The only thing different about the `arrow` function vs. a traditional function in that example is that it closes over `this` (and `arguments` and `super`) — something that you want in that code, because it uses `this` to refer to the object holding `parcels`.

This code that you pointed to:

```
let parcels = this.parcels.map(p => {
    if (p.place != this.place) return p;
    return {place: destination, address: p.address};
})
```

...does the same thing this code using a traditional function does:

```
let _tmp = this; // *** Remember the value `this` has outside the function
let parcels = this.parcels.map(function(p) => {
    if (p.place != _tmp.place) return p;
//                 ^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− use that value here
    return {place: destination, address: p.address};
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was dumb and thought that map would require just arguments, but what it actually does is that it passes the elements to a given function, so I started to thought that arrow functions behaved differently from the usual functions, from this case solely. Again, thank you so much and have a good day!!!

Comment: @RubenRGodPrata - It's not dumb to get confused by this stuff sometimes -- we all do! :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

Arrow functions don't have internal context (this) so they're super useful when you need to access the context from outside the function.

In this case you're using the arrow func inside a map and accessing the context from the class (because move is a method on VillageState it will also have access to `this.place`

Why is this cool? Well if you used a regular function and you tried accessing `this.place` you would get a ReferenceError because there is no place variable defined on the local this.

```js
// dont do this at home
function mapFn(p) {
   /* This here is inside the mapFn and since this.place is not defined 
      we get a ReferenceError */
   if (p.place != this.place) return p;
   return {place: destination, address: p.address};
}

let parcels = this.parcels.map(mapFn)
/* Hopefully the syntax above isn't confussing: 
   * mapFn will be called by default with all the map() parameters
   * inside mapFn we only need p so that's the only name param used
*/
```

## Resources

To learn more about arrow functions I'd check out Impatient JS, it's a really in depth explanation so it should answer most of your questions. The whole 'callable values' chapter is super useful. Also MDN.

https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_callables.html#arrow-functions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to make sense of the higher-order functions in JS with fairly complex example.

First, what does the map method do? It iterates over an array and calls the provided callback function right?!

```html
[1, 2, 3].map(n => n + 1); // [2, 3, 4]

// Which is equalent to this:
[1, 2, 3].map(function(n) { return n + 1 })

// or this...
function increment(n) { return n + 1 };
[1, 2, 3].map(n => increment(n));
```

Or for a better explanation, I would just suggest watching this video to get a clearer understanding of array methods and higher-order functions in JS: [JavaScript Higher Order Functions & Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk)!

And after it would be much easier for you to reason about your concrete example :)